# Placement of "éclatante" + use of definite article

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, articles-definis

Je voudrais faire un site web de la mode (ou seulement « de mode » ? Je ne le sais même pas :( ) qui s'appelle  « éclatant couture ». Mais je ne sais pas si  « éclatante » doit être écrit avant ou après  « couture », selon les règles de grammaire française. C'est-à-dire,

> « éclatant couture »

ou

> « couture éclatant » ?

Et aussi, est-ce qu'il doit y avoir un article défini (dans ce cas « la ») avant le premier mot, c'est-à-dire

> « la couture éclatante » / « l'éclatante couture » ?

Ou puis-je écrire seulement

> « couture éclatante / éclatante couture » ?

Answer (score 4):

Dans le cas d'un titre, ici un nom de site, il n'est pas nécessaire d'écrire un article défini (le/la/les).

*Coutures éclatantes* est le plus approprié.

En français, une grande partie des adjectifs qualificatifs sont écrits après le nom / pronom.
Quelques exceptions existent telles que *une grande maison*,*un joli jardin*, cependant dans ce cas-là, on dit bien *des coutures éclatantes*

Sinon, on dit bien un ***site web de mode***

Comment: La majorité des adjectifs qualificatifs se placent après le nom, mais il y a une grand nombre d'adjectifs (mais pas "éclatant") qui ne suivent pas cette règle: *une grande maison, un joli jardin, un mauvais film*, etc.

Comment: Tu as raison, j'ai modifié ma réponse. Merci pour la précision

Comment: Même si éclatant suit plus souvent le nom qu'il qualifie, rien n'interdit de dire *une éclatante couture* comme on dit *une éclatante victoire* ou une *éclatante confirmation*.

Answer (score 2):

L'adjectif "éclatant" est plus souvent placé après qu'avant le nom qu'il qualifie, mais la différence n'est pas très grande (rapport de 1 à 2) d'après [ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A9clatante%20_NOUN_%2C%20_NOUN_%20%C3%A9clatante&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C3%A9clatante%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_NOUN_%20%C3%A9clatante%3B%2Cc0).

D'un pur point de vue de compréhension, les deux formulations "Éclatante couture" et "Couture éclatante" se valent donc à peu près, avec seulement des différences stylistiques :

- Légère différence de sens selon l'ordre : une couture éclatante, c'est une couture qui a simplement la qualité d'être éclatante, comme n'importe quelle autre chose pourrait l'être. Dans "éclatante couture," le lecteur va d'abord chercher si l'adjectif pourrait avoir un sens spécifique à la couture. Avec "éclatant" c'est moins visible parce que l'usage est dans les deux cas évidemment au figuré, mais si on regarde l'adjectif voisin "brillant", une "couture brillante" c'est une couture qui brille ou qui scintille à la lumière (littéralement), tandis dans "brillante couture" l'adjectif a plutôt le sens de remarquable.
- La prononciation de "Couture éclatante" est plus facile, car le e muet de "couture" est remplacé par le "é" ; on prononce l'ensemble "couturéclatante". Comparer avec "Éclatante couture", où on doit soit se forcer à vocaliser le "e" final (normalement muet) de "Éclatante"  — un peu pompeux, à mon avis personnel — soit on se retrouve avec la rude juxtaposition de consonnes /t'k/. (Est-ce mal pour autant ? Peut-être que pour une marque de mode, être difficile à prononcer donne un gage de sophistication...)

On remarque aussi que cet adjectif est de moins en moins utilisé, ce qui lui conférerait peut-être en tant que marque un côté nostalgique ou ironiquement désuet.